# ExpressionEngine Safecracker Guest Thank you email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expressionengine, safecracker

Is it possible after submitting a safecracker form to send a thank you email to the guest?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on [the ExpressionEngine StackExchange site.](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Would you be comfortable with writing in PHP to deliver this email?

You can edit one of the hooks for Safecracker to perform an action (send an email) on form submission.

`$this->EE->extensions->call('safecracker_submit_entry_start', $this);`

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/development.html